# recursively get item from items change it and add somewhere

Tags: c#, recursion

in this codes, i can get groupItem, but every groupitem has a Items property and every item has an Items property again. how i can change this codes to recursively work?

```
foreach (var groupItem in controlInfoDataGroup.Groups)
        {
            var infoBadgeGroup = GetInfoBadge(groupItem.InfoBadge);

            ControlInfoDataGroup group = new ControlInfoDataGroup(groupItem.Title,...);

            foreach (var itemInfo in group.Items)
            {
                bool isNew = itemInfo.IsNew;
                bool isUpdated = itemInfo.IsUpdated;
                bool isPreview = itemInfo.IsPreview;
                ...
                var item = new ControlInfoDataItem(itemInfo.UniqueId,
                                                        ...);

                item.IncludedInBuild = isIncludedInBuild;

                foreach (var doc in itemInfo.Docs)
                {
                    item.Docs.Add(new ControlInfoDocLink(doc.Title, doc.Uri));
                }
                foreach (var relatedControl in itemInfo.RelatedControls)
                {
                    item.RelatedControls.Add(relatedControl);
                }
                group.Items.Add(item);
            }
            Groups.Add(group);
        }
```

Comment: _"how i can change this codes to recursively work?"_ - What do you consider "work"? WHat is it supposed to do? What about this code as is shown does not do what you expect? Why do you insist on "recursively"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a direction. Instead of this:

```
foreach (var groupItem in controlInfoDataGroup.Groups)
    {
        var infoBadgeGroup = GetInfoBadge(groupItem.InfoBadge);
```

Make a method like this:

```
public void ProcessGroupItems(Item groupItem, ..){ // Transfer the relevant arguments that are relevant for the next iteration.
  if(groupItem.Item ==null){
   //if it is void, dont execute the logic that comes after the closing if statement, if you have return type, then return from the method.
      }
   // Execute all your loop logic.
    }
```